# RED5 HLS Plugin

Tags: red5

When red5 is restarted none of the recorded streams from the previous red5 instance are available. I assume this is by design. Is that correct?
If I wanted to record streams would I take the HLS plugin as a starting point or is there a better way to do recording

Answer (score 1):

When the server is restarted it loses the connections of all the connected publishers and subscribers just like any other server, so obviously the live stream sources for the hls streams will be gone. The segments themselves only exist up to the maximum segment count per stream, this could be set to some really large number to keep all the segments and thus providing a vod type stream. As the creator of the plug-in, I don't recall if vod is supported out-of-the-box, so you'll have to do a little discovery there.

Comment: can we secure HLS stream using your plugin?

Comment: If you put an https connection in front or it instead of the http default, I would assume so.

Comment: thanks for the response, i was asking to secure stream using token and expiry just like wowza server

Comment: You'd have to add that layer to the plugin, its not included